# Adding a custom Jinja2 filter in GAE 1.6.0

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'd like to add filter to format my time and the best would be filters like django's `timesince` that automatically outputs the language of the i18n selected language, but first to make a quick solution I'd like to format my date. The [suggested solution from the manual](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#writing-filters) is:

```
def datetimeformat(value, format='%H:%M / %d-%m-%Y'):
    return value.strftime(format)

jinja_environment.filters['datetimeformat'] = datetimeformat
```

But adding this code to my file doesn't make the filter available in the template:

```
{{ ad.modified|datetimeformat }}
TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'datetimeformat'
```

If I add the code to the Jinja2 library's `filters.py` then it works. But I shouldn't need to add to Jinja2 files manually, it should work just adding the Jinja2 to my `app.yaml` and put my filter in my code instead of in the Jinja2 code. Where should I put the filter code?

Thank you

**Update**

My code looks like this and it seems the filter is not picked up:

```
from django.utils import translation
from django.utils.translation import gettext, ngettext, ugettext, ungettext, get_language, activate
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

class DjangoTranslator(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.gettext = gettext
        self.ngettext = ngettext
        self.ugettext = ugettext
        self.ungettext = ungettext

class DjangoEnvironment(jinja2.Environment):
    def get_translator(self, context):
        return DjangoTranslator()

jinja_environment = DjangoEnvironment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)), extensions=['jinja2.ext.i18n'])
jinja_environment.install_gettext_translations(translation)

def datetimeformat(value, format='%H:%M / %d-%m-%Y'):
    return value.strftime(format)

jinja_environment.filters['datetimeformat'] = datetimeformat
```

Comment: What's `jinja_environment` in this context? Are you sure it's the one you're using to render? Can you link to the docs where this was suggested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following your example and [Jinja2 docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters) I've added custom filter and it works.
Make sure that you use proper `jinja2.Environment` instance for getting template and rendering:

```
env = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_path))
env.filters['default_if_none'] = default_if_none  # a function
tmpl = env.get_template(filename)
tmpl.render(**context)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because I was using a cached  jinja2 environment as recommended [here](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/jinja2.html),

Kee's answer didn't work for me, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10424033/1210075) did.

Specifically, adding the filter when calling `webapp2.WSGIApplication`

```
myconfig = {}
myconfig['webapp2_extras.jinja2'] =  {'template_path': ['templates','blog_posts'],
                                      'filters': {'blog_filter': blog_filter}}

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(_routes,
    debug=True,
    config = myconfig)
```