# how to clean up this jinja2 and/or boolean expression

Tags: python, filter, config, jinja2, webapp2

```
{% block content %}
    {% for blog_dict in blogs|sort(reverse=True,attribute='date') if ((not file_name_filter) or blog_dict.filename==file_name_filter) and ((not category_filter) or blog_dict.category==category_filter) %}
        <div id="post{{blog_dict.post_number}}-{{blog_dict.link_name}}">
            {{blog_dict.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}}
            <a href="/posts/{{blog_dict.filename}}"><h1>{{blog_dict.heading}}</h1></a>
            <!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
            <div class="g-plusone" data-href="/posts/{{blog_dict.filename}}"></div>
            {{blog_dict.post|safe}}
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <img src="/images/page_divider.gif"><br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see the expression is getting messy:

```
{% for blog_dict in blogs|sort(reverse=True,attribute='date') if ((not file_name_filter) or blog_dict.filename==file_name_filter) and ((not category_filter) or blog_dict.category==category_filter) %}
```

The other option I tried was putting two nested if statements in the loop to take care of the two filters, but then nesting got large.

what is the most elegant?

Comment: I would perform the sorting and filtering in your Python code, and pass the result sequence of `blog_dict`s to the template as `blogs`.

Is there a reason why do you need to do it inside the template?

Comment: There are other parts of the template that display previews for all the unfiltered data. So i need to pass all the data. Also I don't want my python script getting too caught up in how the data is displayed, I just want it to provide the data. Not sure if i'm right though.

Comment: You could write a [custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters) that returns the filtered data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As John Keyes mentioned in the comments, I added a filter:

```
def blog_filter(blogs, file_name_filter, category_filter):
    if file_name_filter:
        blogs = (d for d in blogs if d['filename'] == file_name_filter)
    if category_filter:
        blogs = (d for d in blogs if d['category'] == category_filter)
    return blogs
```

this is added to jinja2 environment.filters dict

```
myconfig = {}
myconfig['webapp2_extras.jinja2'] =  {'template_path': ['templates','blog_posts'],
                                      'filters': {'blog_filter': blog_filter}}

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(_routes,
    debug=True,
    config = myconfig)
```

the expression becomes:

```
{% for blog_dict in blogs|blog_filter(file_name_filter,category_filter)|sort(reverse=True,attribute='date') %}
```

I was also able to use this filter elsewhere such as my side menu:

```
{% for month, blog_dicts in blogs|blog_filter(False, category_filter)|groupby('date.month')|sort(reverse=True,attribute='grouper') %}
```

Note I use the jinja2 wrapper (from webapp2_extras import jinja2)
and it is a cached property in my basehandler

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    def render_template(self, filename, **kwargs):
        #call self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(..)
```