# Adding a custom filter to jinja2 on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2, customization

I need to add a very simple filter to jinja2. Basically, it takes a number and appends a '+' if it's positive. I followed the jinja2 docs on how to add custom filters, but it doesn't seem to work (on GAE).

Python:

```
def str_votes(votes):
    if votes > 0:
        return '+' + str(votes)
    else:
        return str(votes)

# jinja2 stuff
template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                               autoescape=True)
jinja_env.globals['str_votes'] = str_votes
```

HTML (for rendered page):

```
<div>{{ 123|str_votes }}</div>
```

This gives me an error of: `TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'str_votes'`

How do I fix this? (There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039925/adding-a-custom-jinja2-filter-in-gae-1-6-0) here that was never answered.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to register the filter. Something like:

```
jinja_env.filters['str_votes'] = str_votes
```

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar by registering it in the globals:

```
    def jinja2(self):
       j.environment.globals['humanize_time']= humanize_time
       return j
```

then calling it with the data we want to pass it in the templates like so:

```
{{ humanize_time(f.last_post_time) }}
```